# Can I define different type for foreign key column from the parent table?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I need to connect to a postgreSQL database in a relation like in the code.
The problem is in the database "id" in table "b" is "bigint" and "b_id" in table "a" is "integer", prod db is not in my control so i can't change it.

"b_id" in "a" is not defined as foreign key, thats probably why postgre did allow that.

As expected, hibernate throws "found [int4 (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [integer (Types#BIGINT)]"

If i create tables via hibernate it defines "b_id" in table "a" as "bigint" as expected

What would be the best way of validating the schema without changing types in the database?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    @NotNull
    private B bId;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Just fix the schema, you are currently trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [columnDefinition](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()) element in your `A` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", columnDefinition = "int")
    @NotNull
    private B bId;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Still throws the same exception.